# Magento2 command not working

Tags: magento2, ssh

I have setup Magento2 on my local system but when i go to git bash and run any command i am getting this error bash: php: command not found.

Comment: instead of php add path of your php  in commad

Answer (score 1):

Use this command :

```
$whereis php
```

O/P (will be like blow):

```
**php: /usr/bin/php7.0**
```

Go to your Magento root Directory and use below command :

```
/usr/bin/php7.0/php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If you are using windows then, follow this :

**php to the path environment variable**

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/

Comment: /usr/bin/env: php’: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the output of this command ?
$whereis php

Comment: please run below command :

$which php

,Then you will get a path like below "/usr/bin/php"

,then run the command :

/usr/bin/php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: which php
which: no php

Comment: Try : $php -v  -is any command working for php on ssh?

Comment: not working i m working on local

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557650/how-can-i-get-php-working-again-in-the-command-line

Comment: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: Which os you are using?

Answer (score 1):

On my server there are multiple php version, for magento commands I use php71 bin/magento ....
You can try php70 (version 7.0) or php71 (version 7.1)